# How do i set role with Supabase?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, supabase, policy

I have been trying to set roles in my supabase database but it doesn't work and i can't find any helpful docs.

So i made a policy that restrain user from seeing other users data with :
`(((auth.jwt() ->> 'sub'::text) = (id)::text)` 
And then i added this :
`(((auth.jwt() ->> 'sub'::text) = (id)::text) OR (auth.role() = 'admin'::text))`
That suposedly would have checked the auth.role() and if the user is admin, then he can can bypass this policy. But it doesn't work. The role of my user is indeed "admin".

Comment: can you share with us the table schema and the full RLS policy ?

Comment: Docs for this here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#authjwt